# Macbook Pro uses Wi-Fi from USB-connected iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi

Whenever I connect my iPhone to my Macbook Pro, it starts using the Wi-Fi from the phone, even though they're connected to the same one. When I disconnect the phone from the computer, the computer uses its own Wi-Fi connection.

This causes problems, e.g. if I'm downloading a large file to my computer with my phone connected and then I disconnect my phone, then the download fails and I'll have to resume it.

What could possibly be causing this? I use a VPN client on both my computer and my phone, but even when I disconnect from the VPN on both devices, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: Is your iPhone higher in the order list of networks than your home wifi name?

Comment: @fsb: No, my iPhone isn't in the list of networks at all. I'm starting to think that maybe the computer isn't even using the iPhone Wi-Fi, maybe something else is happening when I connect/disconnect the phone which causes the network to go down for a second.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have turned on your iPhones hotspot, which also works over USB.

On your iPhone open the `settings` app. Head over to `personal hotspot`. Turn it off and you should be good.

On the Mac side you should be able to check to which network you are connected to by opening the `settings` app and viewing the connected network under the `network` pane.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but unfortunately, I didn't have the hotspot enabled on my phone, so this is probably not the reason. :/